# Why is this solution to Question B6 of the 2015 Putnam wrong?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math, taylor-expansion

This is a reupload. The question in question is:

> For each positive integer $k$, let $A(k)$ be the number of odd divisors of $k$ in the interval $[1,
> \sqrt{2k})$. Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} {{A(k)}\over{k}}$

**The correct answer is $\frac{π^2}{16}$.**

For this, I decided to use the followng method:

> Let us take a simpler function, $B(k)$, which will represent the number of odd divisors of k in the interval $[1, k]$. I realised that for every integer $k$, $\frac{B(k)}{k}$ could be written as $\frac1k + \frac1k + \frac1k + ...$, with a term of $\frac1k$ for every odd divisor of $k$. Or to put simply, $n ⋅ \frac1k$, where $n$ represents the number of odd divisors of $k$. What this means is that, if you had any number $k$ with odd divisors  $k_1, k_2, k_3, ... k_n$, then in the following set of series (or sums to infinity):

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{k_1 ⋅ i} = \frac1{k_1} + \frac1{2 ⋅ k_1} + \frac1{3 ⋅ k_1} + ...$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{k_2 ⋅ i} =\frac1{k_2} + \frac1{2 ⋅ k_2} + \frac1{3 ⋅ k_2} + ...$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{k_n ⋅ i} =\frac1{k_n} + \frac1{2 ⋅ k_n} + \frac1{3 ⋅ k_n} + ...$$

> You will end up having the expression $\frac{B(k)}k$ inside the result of what you will get if you added all the series together. Now, we can extend this concept onto every positive integer $k$, for every odd divisor. The sum of $\frac{B(k)}k$ for every positive integer $k$ can be found by summing together all the reciprocals of all multiples of every odd number:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B(k)}k = \sum_{i \text{ odd}}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{i ⋅ j}$$

> Which of course, diverges. Now, let us try to move one step closer to the original question, by considering the fact that for every even $k$,  $\frac{A(k)}k$ will be multiplied by $-1$. We can this modify the above series involving $\frac{B(k)}k$ to reflect this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \frac{B(k)}k = \sum_{i \text{ odd}}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{i ⋅ j} (-1)^{j-1} = \sum_{i \text{ odd}} \frac1i \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1j (-1)^{j-1} = \ln 2 \cdot \sum_{i \text{ odd}} \frac1i$$

> Which still diverges. Now, it is time to modify $B(k)$ such that it fits the original question. To do this, we will make it such that we are still adding together the reciprocals of the mutiples of every odd number, except we will only begin summation starting from a certain multiple of the odd number ($a ⋅ i$, where $i$ is the odd number), such that $i < \sqrt{2ai} $. To do this, it will be helpful to express what $a$ minimally must be in terms of $i$.

$$i < \sqrt{2ai}$$
$$i^2 < 2ai$$
$$i(i - 2a) < 0$$
$$a > \frac i2 $$

> Since $a$ is supposed to represent a positive integer, but $i$ is an odd number not divisible by $2$, we can rewrite this as

$$a \geq \frac {i+1}2$$

> Therefore, for every odd number $i$, we can only begin addition from $\frac1{i \frac {i+1}2}$ onwards. Note that for any $i$, in the series $\frac1{i \frac {i+1}2} + \frac1{i \frac {i+1}2 + i} + ... \frac1{i \frac {i+1}2 + bi}$, every alternating term's denominator (i.e., the multiple of the odd number) is odd/even, depending on whether the first term is even or odd; this makes sense, because every alternating multiple of any odd number will be even. Whether the denominator of the first reciprocal, $\frac1{i \frac {i+1}2}$ is odd or even, however, alternates with every value of $i$. The reason for this is shown below:

$$\text{Let } i \frac {i+1}2 \text{ be odd. Then, } $$

$$(i+2) \frac {i+3}2 - i \frac {i+1}2 = 2i + 3,  $$

> which is odd. An odd number added with an odd number yields an even number, and hence $(i+2) \frac {i+3}2$ is even. Thus, the overall summation the question asks for can be rewritten as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} {{A(k)}\over{k}} = \sum_{i \text{ odd}} ((-1)^{\frac{i(i+1)}2 - 1} \cdot \frac 1i) \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{\frac {i+1}2 + j} (-1)^{j} \\ = \arctan(1)  \sum_{i \text{ odd}} \ln 2 - \sum_{j=1}^{\frac {i+1}2-1} \frac {(-1)^{j+1}}j $$

> Taking user Gary's suggestions from the comments of a previous version of this post,

$$\ln 2 = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^i {\frac{{( - 1)^{j + 1} }}{j}}  + \int_0^1 {\frac{{( - 1)^i x^i }}{{1 + x}}dx} $$

$$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\ln 2 - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^i {\frac{{( - 1)^{j + 1} }}{j}} } \right)}  = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty  {\int_0^1 {\frac{{( - 1)^i x^i }}{{1 + x}}dx} }  = \int_0^1 {\frac{1}{{1 + x}}\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^i x^i } dx}  = \int_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{(1 + x)^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{2}.$$

$$\arctan(1) \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\ln 2 - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^i {\frac{{( - 1)^{j + 1} }}{j}} } \right)} = \frac{\arctan(1)}2 = \frac π8$$

> This answer is wrong. Is this because of further errors during the working steps? Or is it because of logical errors in reasoning that are fundamental?